# Decrypting an XML file with asymmetric keys

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I have a program that exports a set of database rows. Within the rows is data that needs to be encrypted. I am able to encrypt the data but I cannot seem to decrypt it. I followed the coding shown in [Decrypt Xml file with asymetric key windows forms and windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260031/decrypt-xml-file-with-asymetric-key-windows-forms-and-windows-service) and I'm still receiving the message "Unable to retrieve the decryption key"

Currently this is being done in the same machine under the same user, but that will not always be the case. The exported file will be moved to another machine and imported under a different user.

Here is my Encryption routine...

```
        XmlElement elementToEncrypt;

        var security = new CryptoKeySecurity();
        // Give the creating user full access 
        security.AddAccessRule(new CryptoKeyAccessRule(new NTAccount(Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName), 
            CryptoKeyRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        // Specify that the key is to be stored in the machine key-store, and apply the security settings created above 
        var cspParams = new CspParameters
        {
            KeyContainerName = "XML_ENC_RSA_KEY",
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,
            CryptoKeySecurity = security
        };
        var rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        elementToEncrypt = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName(elementName)[0] as XmlElement;

        var sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged() { KeySize = 256 };

        EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
        byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);

        var edElement = new EncryptedData()
        {
            Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl,
            Id = elementName,
            EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url)
        };

        var ek = new EncryptedKey();
        var encryptedKey = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessionKey.Key, rsaKey, false);

        ek.CipherData = new CipherData(encryptedKey);
        ek.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);
        edElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(ek));

        // Create a new KeyInfoName element. 
        var kin = new KeyInfoName() { Value = elementName };

        // Add the KeyInfoName element to the encryptedKey object. 
        ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(kin);
        edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;
        EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);
```

Here is my Decryption routine....

```
         var cspParams = new CspParameters
        {
            KeyContainerName = "XML_ENC_RSA_KEY",
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore | CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey
        };
        var rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        var exml = new EncryptedXml(xmlDocument);
        exml.AddKeyNameMapping(elementName, rsaKey);
        exml.DecryptDocument();
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Gary